# ie and firefox can not read cookie value while using rewrite apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, internet-explorer, firefox, url-rewriting

I have a strange issue while using IE and firefox however chrome and safari works fine. While i am attempted to use multi language site, i am able to redirect page on root to the involved language path properly, basically i have php code as below;

common.php

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_GET['lang'])) 
{
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30),'/');
}

else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) 
{
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} 

else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) 
{
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} 

else 
{
    $lang = 'en';
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30),'/');
}


    switch ($lang) 
   {
        case 'en':
        $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
        break;

        case 'tr':
        $lang_file = 'lang.tr.php';
        break;
    }

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lang/'.$lang_file);
?>
```

.htaccess as below;

```
RewriteEngine on

# do not use htaccess any of rule when php post
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# add extension if the php file exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

# if cookie set turn /file to /en|tr/file
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=(en|tr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!(tr|en)).*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# if cookie not set then /  to  /en/file
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=
RewriteRule ^((?!(tr|en)).*)$ /en/$1? [L,R=301]

# if cookie set then goto there root folder
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=(en|tr)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(tr|en))$ /%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# get meanful /en|tr/file to /en|tr/file?lang=en|tr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(tr|en)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L]
```

once i try to request `/` it should read the cookie value and turns to `/en/` or `/tr/` based on cookie value however, on ie and firefox it did not work.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You don't indent your code?

Comment: there is no specific code involved since they are regular php files as in used for web pages includes common.php. Issue should related with .htaccess or ie/firefox i am assuming.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache from the 301 permanent redirects and using 302 redirects instead?

Comment: @linuxman I was talking about the PHP code. I find it extremely difficult to read code that is not indented.

Comment: i tried to clear browser cache plus cookies for sure. 302 type of redirect is not a good solution for seo friendly site but no i was not try.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. removing 301 fixed the issue. it is still strange for me if anyone has an answer would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Once remove redirect type 301, then code works for all browsers. Still, i am not sure how this move effects SEO.

```
RewriteEngine on

# do not use htaccess any of rule when php post
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# add extension if the php file exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

# if cookie set turn /file to /en|tr/file
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=(en|tr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!(tr|en)).*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R]

# if cookie not set then /  to  /en/file
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=
RewriteRule ^((?!(tr|en)).*)$ /en/$1? [L,R]

# if cookie set then goto there root folder
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=(en|tr)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(tr|en))$ /%1/$1 [L,R]

# get meanful /en|tr/file to /en|tr/file?lang=en|tr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(tr|en)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Don't do 301 redirects on translation pages. use 307